# SPSS 21 - creating better graphs

Tags: spss

SPSS' default settings for graphs are pretty rudimentary and, generally, ugly.

I have just upgraded from v.12 to v.21 and am very surprised, and extremely disappointed, to see that there is practically no change.

I had high hopes for GPL, but it does not seem to offer anything more than basic settings.

For instance, I want to create a sequence of scatterplots.

The dimension should be 375 points square.
Both axes should go to 1,000. 
The points should be size 1, colour dark red.
The chart background should be white.

I also want to create a sequence of scatterplots.

The dimension should be 375 points square.
X axis should go to 1,000,
Y axis to 160. 
There should be 50 bins - (x-axis, number of intervals). 
Display digit grouping should be on. 
Histogram bar fill and border should be colour a and colour b (these will vary, but should be scripted).

Finally, a set of box plots which also need customisation away from the default settings.

So, is it possible to script customisations like this, or do I have to go through the VERY SLOW and TEDIOUS point and click process for every one?

I HAVE 105 GRAPHS!

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

GPL provides syntax control for all of these things.  The graphics engine in V21 is entirely different and much more flexible than the ancient on in V12.

The Chart Builder UI offers only basic, general controls.  There is a huge amount of functionality in GPL that is not exposed in the CB.  Paste the syntax from that as a starting point, and look at the GPL documentation in the help.  You may also want to create a template with your specifications and use that from the CB as a shortcut.

The GraphBoard editor provides another interface ultimately to the same graphics engine.  It offers more aesthetic control but is harder to customize.

Comment: It all looks complicated and tiresome, but perhaps not as tiresome as repeatedly having to edit 105 graphs. Thanks.

Comment: Been looking at this. What I would call very very basic settings seem to be undocumented. For instance, I have a histogram. I want the graphic to be 375 pixels square. I want the histogram to cover a smaller square within this area. I want the graph background to be white, not grey. The histogram bars to be a pale green, with outilines pale grey and 0.25 weight. None of these options seem to be covered here: http://ons17048:3946/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/idh_graphboard_template_chooser.htm  or in the GPL Reference Guide.pdf. Really very irritating.

Comment: Also cannot see any of these options within GraphBoard.

Comment: GPL would seem to be the answer to all a grapher's needs in SPSS. Anyone who has to produce a series of graphics should be able to use this to impose a common look and feel to them. In my case, I am producing a sequence of histograms, scatterplots and whisker plots.  Now a graph in SPSS compriseses and outer frame, data frame, inner frame and legend frame see the documentation under ibm.spss.statistics.help/idh_webhelp_chart_size_palette.htm  but when it comes to editing these, there only seems to be a point and click route ibm.spss.statistics.help/idh_webhelp_chart_size_palette.htm

Comment: For instance, on "http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v21r0m0/index.jsp" if you enter GPL 'inner (or outer) frame' in the search box you get 0 results. 'GPL data frame' brings up only one tangentially appropriate result, "... The algebra determines how data are combined to specify the position of graphic elements in the graph. That is, the algebra defines the graph dimensions or the data frame in which the graph is drawn". I conclude from this that GPL has no way of affecting the Inner, outer, data or legend frames. Is this correct, please?

Comment: PS the URLs I supplied will probably only work (edited) if you have SPSS installed.